# dxf image format from opencv Mat format

Tags: c++, opencv, dxf

is there a way to save or convert a cv::Mat image to dxf format (C++ lang)?

I'm using Opencv to detect borders of some objects in an image and i need the dxf version of the resulting image. I searched for some code but no luck..

Ty

Comment: If you can't find any code, maybe implement it yourself referring https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf

Comment: @kiner_shah ty for the tip, i will definitely try